# Customize commitlint with conventional commit + JIRA Ticket

Tags: git-commit, commitlint

I am using commit lint and I want to use conventional commits but i want to include a Jira Ticket.

Example `TEST-23: fix: my body`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case I needed to create a custom parser and a plugin with a custom rule.